# Is there a neat way to import multiple exports from a module as a namespace in js?

Tags: javascript

In js, is there a neat way to do things like

```js
import { export1, export2 } as ns from 'some-module'
```

and then use `ns.export1` and `ns.export2` later in the code?

I prefer not to import the whole module but meanwhile be able to encapsulate the selected exports in a namespace.

Comment: how about `import * as ns from 'some-module`  ?

Comment: but why do you need them to be wrapped by `ns` ?  why not simply use `export1` and `export2` ?

Comment: @CodeManiac actually I am currently using `export1` and `export2` on their own, but it looks a bit messy, especially when mixed up with exports from other modules. my plan now is to manually put them into an object if one day I can't tolerate it any more. just asking to find any better ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do: `import { export1 , export2 } from 'some-module';`

And just use `export1` or `export2`